# finding the UMPU test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

When trying to find the uniformly most powerful unbiased (UMPU) test for the exponential family Lehmann and Romano give a "simple" approach.

Suppose that we want to test $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ and $H_1: \theta \neq \theta_0$.

Denote by $T(X)$ the sufficient statistic of the exponential family, and by $\phi$ the test which is

$$\phi(x) = I(T(X) < C_1 \cup T(X) > C_2), $$

i'll assume for sake of simplicity that $X$ follows a continuous distribution (avoid dealing with $T(X) = C_1$ or $C_2$).

The UMPU test is one that satisfies the following,

$$ E_{\theta_0} \phi(X) = \alpha, $$

and

$$ E_{\theta_0} [ T(X) \phi(X) ] = E_{\theta_0}[T(X)]\alpha. $$

Is constructing the shortest possible acceptance region (under $\theta_0$) will necessarily yield an UMPU test (for the exponential family, or any other assumptions?)? If not, is there a counter example?

Let $f_{\theta}$ be the density function of $Y$. The shortest possible acceptance region is $\mathcal{R} = \{y: f_{\theta_0}(y) > k\}$, and $k$ is the maximal value which guarantees $P_{\theta_0} ( y \in \mathcal{R}) = \alpha$.

Comment: Working on a specific problem might help you understand this better.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you think I understand or misunderstanding. If you can point me to what leads you to believe I have a deep misunderstanding of the topic in my question.

Comment: Nobody is saying you have a deep misunderstanding of the topic; there is a difference between misunderstanding ("wrong answer") and lack of understanding ("don't know the answer"), the latter of which is evidenced by the fact that you asked the question :)

Comment: What do you mean by `shortest possible'?

Comment: I've added an explanation to what I mean by shortest. But basically, the shortest acceptance region (in terms of length) for which the type I error probability is controlled.